# Installation issues for aptana studio 3.0 in windows xp

Tags: aptana

I want to install aptana studio 3.0, I have downloaded, when run the .exe file, it will nothing happen.

May i know what is the reason, and please help me what is the way to install.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not able to execute the installer then follow the below steps

1) change the extension from .exe to .rar

2) open this file by using Winrar or 7z, I mean to say just extract it.

Comment: what is the link between JAVA and aptana?

Comment: Windows installer of Aptana studio includes a compatible version of Java.Java is required to run Aptana studio, for more details about java and aptana do google.

Comment: are you there? @prashant thakre

Comment: Did you try this link to download http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download

Comment: yes, after enter my details, it started download. after downloaded, .exe file doesn't work.

Comment: we need to go for chat option as per policy its not good to have multiple comments let me check how to start chat.